# Indefinite Search Cluster (Solr vs ES vs Datastax EE)

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, datastax-enterprise

**PREFACE:**

This question is not asking for an open ended comparison of Elastic Search vs. Solr vs. Datastax Solr (Datastax EE). (Though links in comments section for this are welcome).

**PROJECT:**

I have been building a domain name type web service for a while. In doing so, I am realizing the exponential growth of such service.

**BACKGROUND:**

I would like to know which specific search platform allows me to save and expand indefinitely. Yes, I realize you can split a Solr Shard these days– so if I have a 20 shard solr cloud I can later split them into 40 (I think? Again... that's not indefinate). Not sure on the Elastic Search side of things.  Datastax (EE) seems to be the answer because of Cassandra’s architecture but (A) Since they give no transparency on license price – and I have to disclose my [earnings](http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise/startups) to them I'm quickly reminded of Oracle's bleed you slowly fee strategy and as I start-up that is a huge deterrent. Also, (B) When they say they integrate full MapReduce with Hive, Sqop, Mahout, Solr, and Pig – I’m thinking I don’t want to spend a lifetime learning bells and whistles that aren’t applicable to my project. I want a search platform that I can add 2 billion documents a month (or whatever number) indefinitely and not have to worry that I started a cluster with too little shards upfront.

**QUESTION:**

Admittedly my background section is pilfered with ignorance that I would like to correct. My intention is not to offend or dilute these amazing technologies. I am simply wondering which of them can scale w/o having to worry about overgrowing shards [*I took out the word forever here -- thank you per comment below*]. Or can any? Not hardware-wise, but Shards. Which platform can I use and not have to worry about the future growth whether its 20TB or 2PB. Assume hardware budget for servers, switches, etc. etc. are indefinite.

Comment: Elastic search handles growth very well. You can add JVMs (nodes) on new boxes with little effort. The cluster will attempt to shuffle shards there and keep a nice balance of shards. It can also set up replicas and make sure they are not on the same node as the primary shards. Forever is not a term I would apply to any technology. I would guess at some point the network overhead of the scattering and gathering a big query on a *forever* sized cluster will become large.

Comment: @mconlin This is VERY helpful. I see there is a book on ES but it looks like it uses v.2 when v.9 is current. Have there been significant changes enough render .2 too old? What is best way to learn / How did you learn ES? THANK YOU AGAIN...

Comment: .20 to .90 is very pretty different. They have lots of good posts and videos on their site including good ones on scaling. I use it at work and am constantly learnIng still.

Comment: @mconlin does ES actually allow me to add shards on-the-go though? like if I start a 10 node 10 server cluster, can I later add 10 more shards w/10 associated servers?

Comment: yes, its super easy to add additional nodes. You can run many nodes per physical machine as well. Great videos here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/

Comment: I wonder why you explicitly mentioned "splitting shards" as a needed feature. Although it does seem promising, splitting shards is really expensive and requires to reindex part of the data. Elasticsearch doesn't allow to split shards because of those downsides, but provides the tools to be able to scale out without splitting shards. Have a look at [aliases](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) and [this talk](http://vimeo.com/44716955).

Answer (score 1):

DataStax Enterprise (DSE) is not a "search platform" per se. One of the features DSE provides is the ability to search data stored in Cassandra. Cassandra is being used to store and access enterprise operational data. The idea is that once you have decided that Cassandra is your preferred data store for your enterprise operational data, the DSE/Solr integration then allows you to perform rich search on that data.

Large enterprises are looking to migrate off of traditional relational databases, to more modern platforms such as NoSQL databases, such as Cassandra, where scalability and distributed computing (including multi-data center support, tunable consistency, and robust operations tools, including the OpsCenter GUI dashboard) are the norm. The Solr integration of DSE facilitates that migration.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your revenue, that link points to a startup program.  That makes the software 100% free if you qualify.